# When scaling, run some docker container startup commands only once

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following `docker-compose.yml`.

```yaml
version: "3.1"

services:
  db:
    container_name: ${MYSQL_CONTAINER}
    image: mysql:5.7.30
    volumes:
      - ${VOLUMES_DIR}/mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./slow_log.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
      - ${VOLUMES_DIR}/mysql_logs:/var/log/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}
    ports:
        - ${MYSQL_PORT}:3306
    entrypoint: ""
    command: bash -c "chown -R mysql:mysql /var/log/mysql && exec /entrypoint.sh mysqld --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password"
    restart: on-failure

  backend:
    container_name: ${BACKEND_CONTAINER}
    image: ${BACKEND_IMAGE}
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - ${BACKEND_PORT}
    command: >
      bash -c "command A
      && command B
      && ... "
    restart: unless-stopped
```

I am scaling backend service so my startup command is `sudo docker-compose -p ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME} up -d --scale backend=10`.

The problem I am facing is command A, command B in service `backend` was running for all 10 containers startup(means they were being run 10 times).
But I want `command A` to run only once for all the `backend` service-related containers but `Command B` should run for all containers.

Any suggestions in accomplishing this?

Comment: whats command A?

Comment: A command that is dependant on `db` service. Basically it creates a database and its tables based on some files from BACKEND_IMAGE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure that there would be an out-of-the-box solution for your requirement.

However, I can suggest you a workaround like this. You can duplicate your backend service in docker-compose and run one backend service with both `Command A` and `Command B`, while the other backend has only `Command B`.

Then when you want to scale, you scale the backend which has only `Command B`.

```sh
version: "3.1"

services:
  db:
    container_name: ${MYSQL_CONTAINER}
    image: mysql:5.7.30
    volumes:
      - ${VOLUMES_DIR}/mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./slow_log.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
      - ${VOLUMES_DIR}/mysql_logs:/var/log/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}
    ports:
        - ${MYSQL_PORT}:3306
    entrypoint: ""
    command: bash -c "chown -R mysql:mysql /var/log/mysql && exec /entrypoint.sh mysqld --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password"
    restart: on-failure

  backend_default:
    container_name: ${BACKEND_CONTAINER}
    image: ${BACKEND_IMAGE}
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - ${BACKEND_PORT}
    command: >
      bash -c "command A
      && command B
      && ... "
    restart: unless-stopped

  backend:
    container_name: ${BACKEND_CONTAINER}
    image: ${BACKEND_IMAGE}
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - ${BACKEND_PORT}
    command: >
      bash -c "command B
      && ... "
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Now you can use the `scale` option like below:

```sh
sudo docker-compose -p ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME} up -d --scale backend=9
```

Now if there happens to be a scenario, where you need only 1 backend to be run, you can use [profiles in docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/) to only run `backend` when there is a specific profile is given with docker-compose command. That means only `default_backend` will run if that profile is not given and hence the scale is 1.

Hope this helps you. Cheers  !!!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If I didn't get any better answers will follow this approach.

Answer (score 0):

If `BACKEND_IMAGE` is being built by you, you should do `RUN command A` in your Dockerfile. The `RUN` line will be executed only once during build time — so you will also need to make sure that this meshes with your needs — while the `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` lines will only be run upon execution of the container. The `command` in the docker-compose file overrides the `CMD` line.

Comment: Backend service has a dependency on the db service. So I cannot run command A at image build time.